# Get value of CSS rule from CSS module

Tags: css, reactjs, dry, css-modules

Let's say I have a React component with a simple CSS module:

```css
/* MyComponent.module.css */
.animatable {
    background-color: red;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.animating {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.js
import styles from "./MyComponent.module.css"


const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false)

    const classes = `${styles.animatable} ${isAnimating? styles.animating : ''}`

    const clickHandler = () => {
        setIsAnimating(true)

        setTimeout(() => setIsAnimating(false), 500)
    }

    return <div className={classes} onClick={clickHandler}>Click me.</div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

There is a little code duplication in that the CSS `transition-duration` and the `setTimeout()` to revert the animation both hard-code the duration.

I think it would make sense to have a single source of truth and that it can be the CSS, since it's the "most static" of the two files. From the js file I have access to `styles` from the CSS module, but is there a way to fetch that `transition-duration: 500ms` so that I can reuse it?

Comment: This is probably too much of a change for something like this, but an alternative approach could be to [listen for the end of the animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) and update, rather than using a timeout.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a [CSS Custom Property (CSS Variable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) as a single source of truth that can be accessed easily and natively in both the CSS file and in JS.

Comment: I had thought of the CSS property approach, and it's probably what I'd go for, it seems cleaner and less error-prone. I wasn't aware of `animationend_event` though, that's good to know!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to listen for the `transitionend` event instead of using `setTimeout`:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false)
  const ref = useRef()

  const classes = `animatable ${isAnimating ? 'animating' : ''}`

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setIsAnimating(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAnimating) return

    const transitionendHandler = () => {
      setIsAnimating(false)
    }

    ref.current.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionendHandler)

    return () => {
      ref.current.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionendHandler)
    }
  }, [isAnimating])

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={classes}
      onClick={clickHandler}
    >
      Click me.
    </div>
  )
}
```